# Как отладить тест яваскрипт на mocha в visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, юнит-тесты, отладка, mocha

Написал код который хочу протестировать. Код представляет из себя навык Алисы и запускает сервер принимающий джейсон и отправляющий джейсон в ответ.
Написал тест для своего кода. Тест вот такой:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import UserT from 'alice-tester';// https://github.com/vitalets/alice-tester
import { after, before, it } from 'mocha';
import Server from './index.js';

before((done) => {
  Server.start(3000, done);
  });

after((done) => {
  Server.stop(done);
  });

it('should get welcome message', async () => {
  const user = new UserT('http://localhost:3000');
  await user.enter();
  console.log(`!TEST:${user.response.text}`);
  assert.equal(user.response.text, 'Привет!');
});
```

(alice-tester - готовит джейсон для навыка и парсит возвращаемый. Специально для упрощения тестирования сделан)
После запуска теста выкладывается такой лог:

```
> memorizer@1.0.0 test
> mocha test.js --timeout 10000



Сервер запущен на 3000 порту: http://localhost:3000
  1) should get welcome message
Сервер остановлен.

  0 passing (10s)
  1 failing

  1) should get welcome message:
     Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (E:\Backup\git\yandex\memorizer\test.js)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

Сервер при этом продолжает выполняться. И после принудительной остановки пишет:

```
PS E:\projects\memorizer> user
о повторите попытку.
строка:1 знак:1
+ user
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (user:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Suggestion [3,General]: Команда user не найдена, однако существует в текущем расположении. По умолчанию оболочка Windows PowerShell не загружает команды из текущего расположения. Если вы уверены в надежности команды, введите ".\user". Для получения дополнительных сведений вызовите справку с помощью команды "get-help about_Command_Precedence".
```

Зачем он пытается выполнить `user` - непонятно.

Для запуска и остановки сервера из теста нарисовал вот такой классик:

```
export default class Server  {
  static server;
  static httpTerminator;
  static started;
  static start(port, done) {
    this.server = app.post('/', (req, res) => {
        parse_alise_request(req).then((ret) => {
        res.json(reply`${ret}`);
        });
    }).listen(port);
    this.httpTerminator = createHttpTerminator({
      server: this.server,
    });
    console.log('Сервер запущен на 3000 порту: http://localhost:3000');
    this.started = true;
    if(typeof (done) === 'function'){
      done();
    }
  } // process.env.PORT

  static stop(done) {
    //_stop;
    this.server.close();
    this.httpTerminator.terminate();
    console.log('Сервер остановлен.');
    if(typeof (done) === 'function'){
      done();
    }
  }
}
```

Попытался отладить как-то этот тест, это же по идее яваскрипт, однако не понял как написать в конфиге VSCode:

```
    {
        "name": "Отладка теста",
        "program": "mocha ${workspaceFolder}\\test.js",
        "request": "launch",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "node"
    },
```

Пробовал `"program": "${workspaceFolder}\\test.js",` - тоже не запускается.

Подскажите как-то можно отлаживать эти тесты по шагам, так же как и простые файлы Nodejs?

И может тут какая-то ошибка очевидная увидится? Или предложения по какому-то другому способу поиска и исправления данной проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче просто отключил использование mocha и его компонентов. Примерно так:

```
import UserT from 'alice-tester';// https://github.com/vitalets/alice-tester
import Server from './index.js';

Server.start(3000);
const user = new UserT('http://localhost:3000');
await user.enter();
console.log(`!TEST:${user.response.text}`);
```

Так отлаживается весь код включая обратабываемый сервером.